# Use External API for Products in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We’ve implemented a shop using Woocommerce and it works great. Now we got a new requirement: We should include products from an external provider using their API. Those are real and digital products and are not listed in our WP backend. It should be possible for customers to buy the products from our shop that is just integrated via the API. We don't want to store the data to the WP database as these products are also used in some other applications. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Follow their API documentation?

Comment: I did but how do I incorporate those products with Woocommerce without saving them into wp database?

Comment: @InayathullahKhan I don't think what you want to do is possible (having products appear in your store without being present in the wordpress database.  As the Order items and such relate to items stored in the DB.  You can however save them  in your DB and set a WP-Cron task to regularly check stock levels with your API call.

Comment: Can't we achieve this with a custom plugin or something @HowardE? This is something I am looking for.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I don't understand why you wouldn't keep the items in your Database.  You can maintain the sync with a cron.

Comment: @HowardE Is there a way we can save/push the product details on creation/on updating the product details?